# What's the difference between $('x > y'), $('y', 'x'), and $('x y')?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The three jQuery selectors below all have the same result. What is the difference?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <p><span>Hello</span>, how are you?</p>
<p>Me? I'm <span>good</span>.</p>
<script>
  $('p > span').css('color','red');
OR
  $('span', 'p').css('color','red');
OR
  $('p span').css('color','red');
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('span', 'p')` and `$('p span')` are identical, both will select any span elements that are descendants of any p element no matter the depth.

`$('p > span')` on the other hand will select span elements that are direct children of the p element. So for example this selector would *not* select the span element in the following example:

```
<p>
    <a href="#">
        <span>Test</span>
    </a>
</p>
```

..whereas the other two would select it just fine.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that `p > span` only matches if the span is a direct decendant of the paragraph.

Given this markup:

```
<p><div><span>Hello</span>, how are you?</div></p>
<p>Me? I'm <span>good</span>.</p>
```

the selector `p > span` would only match the span in the second paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

First is [child-selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

Second is [multiple-selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Third is [descendant-selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)

All links are to the jquery API

Comment: No, the second is not a multiple selector, it's two selectors where the second is used as context for the first. A multiple selector would be `$('span, p')`, which of course doesn't give the same result as the others.